# Can the Bash shell "Ignore" Excess copy-paste text?

Tags: shell, command-line, clipboard, user-interface, input-method

Say, I have a "Quick&Dirty" Perl script in a gui text editor, and I start the Perl interpreter in a terminal window which is running Bash. I can copy-paste the Perl script to the terminal & press CTRL-D to execute it with Perl. Perl will interpret the script and execute it.

Sometimes, there is a typo in the script, which makes Perl print a FATAL ERROR and exit, but the remaining copy-paste text is given to the Bash shell which tries to execute that; Either that fails (lucky case) or executes but will Do something Different (unlucky case).

Eg : start Perl in Bash Prompt , copy-paste a script of 5 lines : lines 1 & 2 are fine , but line 3 makes Perl exit abnormally , hence line 4 & 5 are executed by Bash.

I am using Perl & Bash only for example; Problem can happen with many other interactive tools ( Eg Python, fdisk ) and other shells ( Eg zsh, csh )

Is there any way to inform the shell that this text is a copy-paste input and can be ignored ?
Something like "If faster than user can normally type, then Ignore" ?
Or something like "If Process finished, then flush input buffer before reading next shell input" ?

[[ Some tools do not have this problem, Eg MySQL cli will never exit on improper input. ]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an answer, but maybe it's an acceptable work-around:

```
alias p='perl; echo hit control-d again; cat > /dev/null'
```

Then, if your perl script exits prematurely, you'll harmlessly paste the remainder to /dev/null; if the perl script succeeds, you'll see your friendly reminder and hit control-d to exit the `cat` catcher.

Comment: Brilliant Solution !!

Comment: let's settle for "nice workaround" :) It is a flexible enough idea to adapt for any other tool (python, fdisk, etc). You could confuse yourself by getting fancy with `alias perl=command perl; echo ...cat...` so that you don't have to remember to type 'perl', but ...

Comment: Out of curiosity : Did you come up with a solution (I mean "workaround") right now ? Or were you a victim of this problem earlier ?

Comment: I've written quite a bit of command-line perl, but have never suffered a copy/paste overflow. Since I don't have a good shell-centric solution, the bit bucket came to mind!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the "solution/work-around" by Jeff Schaller , the proper solution seems to be to make the environment aware of copy-paste, both from sender side and from receiver side, which is known as "bracketed paste mode".
From https://cirw.in/blog/bracketed-paste , here is a short snippet to explain a little more :

> In summary:
>
> 1. Enable bracketed paste: printf "\e[?2004h"
> 2. Wait for paste to start: you'll see \e[200~ on STDIN.
> 3. Wait for paste to stop: you'll see \e[201~ on STDIN.
> 4. Disable bracketed paste: printf "\e[?2004l"

It is not yet fully available for Bash, so I will be accepting the answer by Jeff Schaller, which works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pasting into the terminal, have the command read from the clipboard. You can use [xclip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xclip/) or [xsel](http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel/) to print the clipboard content (or conversely write their input to the clipboard).

```
xsel | perl           # automatic selection (click+drag, middle click)
xsel -b | perl        # manual selection (Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V)
```

This only works if the shell in the terminal has access to the X server. It doesn't work, for example, across an SSH session that doesn't forward the X11 connection.

On OSX, use [`pbpaste`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbpaste.1.html) to retrieve the pasteboard content.