# Tool that can be piped into to require a confirmation prompt

Tags: bash

Is there a *nix tool that can be piped into that forces a confirmation prompt before executing all previous commands?  I'm thinking of a tool that would allow you to put commmand line snippets on a web page but guarantee that cut-and-pasting of the command and accidentally pasting a CR/LF wouldn't cause damage to the target's computer.

Here's a simple example assuming there's a tool called 'confirm' and replacing the dev with 'safedev':

```
head -c 32 /dev/urandom | sudo openssl enc -rc4 -nosalt -pass stdin -in /dev/zero -out /dev/safedev | confirm
```

This question stems from my own experience of wrecking my mbr by cut and pasting a command from a browser and it unexpectedly grabbing the CR/LF and begin executing before I had a chance to change sda to sdc.  I was forced to recreate the mbr and reinstall Ubuntu Gnome over my existing partitions in order to recover/recreate my main OS.

If this tool doesn't exist, is there another way of providing commands on a webpage that can force confirmation before executing the commands?  Maybe something like this?

```
confirm && head -c 32 /dev/urandom | sudo openssl enc -rc4 -nosalt -pass stdin -in /dev/zero -out /dev/safedev
```

Comment: Seems similar: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/260395/117549

Comment: Even for the sake of a toy example, you shouldn't use `openssl enc`. People might get the impression that it can be used securely, whereas it pretty much can't.

Comment: @Gilles+ and even though here you're only using `enc` as a cheapish PRNG, there is a 1/4 chance it produces less-random output than you expect and about a 1/16 chance it produces output that could be broken if you actually depended on its randomess, which in this case contrary to the tinfoil-hatters and checklisters you don't.

Answer (score 4):

If you are pasting copied text into a terminal with embedded CRLFs, no prefixed command can save you (and indeed, tacking a command onto the *end* of a pipeline would be closing the door after all the cows have left the barn).  Some terminal emulators (e. g. *iTerm2* on OSX) have recently added CRLF detection and interception to mitigate this sort of problem.

Once you have solved the problem of embedder CRLFs, you can probably fake what you want with something like:

```
/bin/false && ( your commands here )
```

Once you have verified what you want is what you have, you can remove the `/bin/false &&`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ getraw --delay=1 'vent warp core? [yn]' && vent_warp_core
```

[`getraw`](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/misc/getraw) (and the [docs](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/misc/getraw.1) and the [tests](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/misc/t/getraw.t)) could also be done with a `read` call in shell code, I guess.

This also should work in a pipeline, or within a `while` loop if there needs to be a per-file prompt. Totally contrived example:

```
find . -type f | ( getraw 'ready to cat?' && cat )
```

Comment: So far this looks the closest to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [DopeGhoti's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/335476/80216#335479), but less rocket-sciencey:
just type `#` :

```
# ( your commands here )
```